# Why proper ideal doesn't contain $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

Why $I$ is a proper ideal implies $1\notin I$?

The definition of proper ideal only requires $I\neq R$. I don't get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an ideal $I$, if $a\in I$ and $r\in R$, then $ra\in I$. So, if $1\in I$ then $r=r1\in I$ for all $r\in R$; therefore $I=R$.